# Django Login failing

Tags: django, forms, authentication

I'm trying to make a user login view, and It keep failing. This is my code:

```
def userLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = authenticate(username = request.POST['username'], password = request.POST['password'])
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)
                            return HttpResponseRedirect("/success")
                    else:
                        return render_to_response('/home/dockedin/webapps/linked/myproject/templates/index.html', {'outcome':'Account Disabled'}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
                else:
                    return render_to_response('/home/dockedin/webapps/linked/myproject/templates/index.html', {'outcome':'Invalid Login'}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
            else:
                return render_to_response('/home/dockedin/webapps/linked/myproject/templates/index.html', {'outcome':'FORM NOT VALID?'}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))

    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response('/home/dockedin/webapps/linked/myproject/templates/index.html', {'form':form}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

Basically, I keep getting "FORM NOT VALID" printed in my site and I have no clue why. Help Please? Thank you

Comment: While I'm here I should also mention that the way you are trying to render a template seems incorrect. Providing the full path in render_to_response is usually unnecessary. The TEMPLATE_LOADERS setting contains an app_directories_loader; meaning you can save your templates into /application/templates/template.html and reference them in your view like so `'application/template.html'`, provided your application is listed in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Huh, Interesting. I'll keep that in mind. But what if the views.py file isn't in any specific app. Do i just do myproject/index.html? Cause that didnt work when I tried. Maybe my settings are wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print the `form.errors` to see why the validation fails.

BTW, is there a reason that you don't use the built-in [`django.contrib.auth.views.login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login) view?

Comment: Agreed, use the built in view if possible. I think the OP is just beginning to learn django, and isn't aware of the handy built ins like the view you mention.

Comment: Ya, that saved me a lot of time. lol. Quick question, is it possible to get the login to redirect to some other location besides "/accounts/profile"? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

This code is wrong:

```
form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
```

You need to change to:

```
form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
```

It is because AuthenticationForm overwrites `__init__` method and first parameter of constructor is not `data`, but `request=None`.

Some tips:

- Please, reuse included login view as @piquadrat suggested.
- If You are using Django 1.3, please use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut instead of render_to_response + passing `RequestContext`. If You are using Django<1.3 backport render shortcut and use it.
- Do not hardcode template absolute paths; use [settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/settings/#template-dirs)

Comment: Huh, interesting. i'll keep that in mind if I decide to use to auth form. Probably going to go with the built-in view. Thank you though.

Comment: Thank you - this saved me a lot of time. Not an obvious cause of that error!

Answer (score 3):

You're approaching the concept of Django forms incorrectly. The idea of a Form within django, is that it processes the POST data so you don't have to. It isn't simply about validating that the data is correct. They may also transform data into a reliable state.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        login(request, form.get_user())
```

Note that there is no need to manually authenticate? The form instance does the authentication when you check if the form is valid. It is then simply a matter of logging the user in, by retrieving the user instance from the form itself.

You should very rarely (if ever) have to access POST data from within your views. Forms should be used for processing, scrubbing, validating, and returning valid objects.

Comment: This assumes that the form being used is the built in contrib.auth AuthenticationForm. If you aren't using it, you probably should be.